# Modify only first n elements and return the modified array in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I need to perform an operation on `k` set of values of an array and return the modified array.

I have an `array = [10,32,5,6,7]`

Let us say `k=2`

I am trying to take only the first two elements here by doing:

```
arr2=[]
array[0..k-1].each do |i|
 res=i.to_f/2.0
 arr2.push(res.round)
end

=>arr2=[5,16]
```

I want to replace the first 2 elements in the `array` with `arr2` values.
How can I achieve this without having to create so many new arrays.

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to iterate the entire array.

```
array = [10,32,5,6,7]

array[0, 2] = array[0, 2].map { |n| n/2.0 }
array
  #=> [5.0, 16.0, 5, 6, 7]
```

or

```
2.times { |i| array[i] = array[i]/2.0 }
array
  #=> [5.0, 16.0, 5, 6, 7]
```

The above reflects my understanding that the original array is to be mutated. If the array is not to be mutated one could write the following.

```
array[0, 2].map { |n| n/2.0 }.concat(array[2..-1])
  #=> [5.0, 16.0, 5, 6, 7] 
array
  #=> [10, 32, 5, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to push to a new array, why not do:

```
array = [10,32,5,6,7]
k = 2

array[0..k-1].each_with_index do |val, indx|
  array[indx] = val / 2 # or whatever processing really
end
```

This is a simple way to solve your problem as .each_with_index is doing the work here and allows you to modify the initial array easily. This will output:

```
[5, 16, 5, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with your current implementation? Nothing, you just need to sum the other elements from array:

```
arr2=[]
array[0..k-1].each do |i|
 res=i.to_f/2.0
 arr2.push(res.round)
end
arr2 + array[k..-1] # [5, 16, 5, 6, 7]
```

- Whenever you do `integer.to_f / ...`, you can do `fdiv`.
- Instead of assigning a "memo" array, you can use `map`:

```
arr2 = array[0..k-1].map do |i|
  res=i.to_f/2.0
  res.round
end + array[k..-1]
arr2 # [5, 16, 5, 6, 7]
```

- Instead of doing `k - 1` to get a range, you can use an exclusive range `0...k`.

Your code would look like (without modifying `array`):

```
array[0...k].map { |i| i.fdiv(2.0).round } + array[k..-1] # [5, 16, 5, 6, 7]
```